# Should I accept a suggested edit which only improved the post partially?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Example: if there's a missing tag, typos, and unformatted code blocks in a huge post.

Should I accept an edit that only adds the tag? (Assuming that currently, I don't want to improve the post).